# Animation of a bitmap file working on windows but don't on linux

Tags: c, linux, windows, bmp

First, sorry about this title i didn't know how to write this in a smart way..

Actually, i work on a small project for school to learn basis of bitmap manipulation.
So far everything is working smoothly, but when i come back at home on some linux distro (already made sources compatibles with both OS)..ALMOST everything's still working fine.

The problem is that i have an image array to animate a character and this little one is only animated under windows, while on the other OS it stays on array[0] during all animation (the script create 290+ bmp files and after that i run with imagemagick **convert -delay 2 *.bmp -loop 0 test.gif**)

Any ideas ?

Here my complete program :
https://github.com/OkTekk/SchoolProject1

Here the small part of code (it start at line 279 of main.c) :

```
   for(i = 1; i <= 295; i++) {
        Copier_Pixel(img, background);

        if(i%3 == 0) j = j++;
        if(j == 3) j = 0;

        if(i%4 == 0) k = k++;
        if(k == 4) k = 0;

        Ajouter_Calque(img, nuage_ar, 150, i-100);

/****************** Animation Bird ****************/
        if(i <= 32)
            Ajouter_Calque(img, oiseau[j], 250-i/2, 450-2*i);

        if(i >= 33 && i <= 125)
            Ajouter_Calque(img, oiseau[j], 250-i, 450-2*i);

        if(i >= 126) {
            Ajouter_Calque(img, oiseau[j], 125+m, 450-2*i);
            m++;
        }
/**************************************************/

        Ajouter_Calque(img, nuage_av, 200, 400-3*i);

/***************** Animation Mario ****************/
        if(i <= 32)
            Ajouter_Calque(img, mario[k], 93, 2*i);

        if(i >= 33 && i <= 69) {
            x = 1;
            px1 = 1100 + x;
            py1 = f(500, x, 50, 15);

            Ajouter_Calque(img, mario[k], 95-o, 2*i);       // To-do : f() ou fNeg() de px1/py1

            o++;
            x++;
        }

        if(i >= 70 && i <= 125)
            Ajouter_Calque(img, mario[k], 59, 2*i);

        if(i >= 126 && i <= 200) {
            Ajouter_Calque(img, mario[k], 59+p/2, 2*i);
            p++;
        }
/**************************************************/
```

Comment: Your question is unclear - WHAT does not work? Does your software make the BMP files correctly - if it does, why are you showing it to us? If it doesn't make the BMP files correctly, how can it work on Windows?

Comment: The posted code has lots of 'magic' numbers. 'magic' numbers make the code difficult understand, difficult to debug and/or maintain.  Suggest using #defines or an enum to give the numbers meaningful names.

Comment: the letter 'o' is difficult, in many fonts, to distinguish from the number '0' (an early outer space mission failed for this very reason).   The variable names seem (from the posted code) to be meaningless.  For understandability, Suggest using meaningful names for variables

Comment: @MarkSetchell the BMP files are indeed created but while on windows, the character "move" (from mario[0] to mario[4] and for the bird 0 to 2) it dont when compiled under linux..both stay in position 0

Comment: @user3629249 sorry, it probably have more meaning in my native language..? (french) perhaps i can explain some parts to you ? and about the 'magic' numbers...i don't understand what you mean by that

Comment: When indenting code, do not use tabs,  because each word processor/editor has the tab stops/tab width set differently..

Comment: here is some examples of the the 'magic' numbers:  295, 3, 4, 50, 100, 32, 33, 125, 126, 250, 450, 200,400, 69, 93, 40, 15, 50, ....

Comment: So, under Windows you get 290 *different* BMP files that ImageMagick can animate and your bird and clouds move, but on Linux you get 290 identical BMP files in which nothing moves. Correct?

Comment: when writing header files, in general, it is best to have one header file per source file, rather than mixing the globally visible prototypes, etc all into a single header files.   This strongly relates to such concepts as localization/hiding of data, reduction of complexity, reduction of interconnections (logical, data, etc) between different parts of the program. modularity (one function only handles one thing, one file only contains related functions,)

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes, under windows i have all files with mario and oiseau moving from [0] to [4] with
    if(i%3 == 0) j = j++;
    if(j == 3) j = 0;
while under linux, on all the 290 files both objects are only mario[0] and oiseau[0]

Comment: @user3629249 thanks for the advices, i take notes...really. but right not this isn't my concern :) my teacherdid wanted to have a single header file so let it be that way even if i don't like that neither